# How to get ranges of groups of data in sqlite table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm not sure if this can be done but if it can:

Suppose I have a simple table that has a time field (for simplicity sake we'll just use integers) and a activity field.  The data can be sorted on time.  For example:

```
| time  |  activity
--------------------
|  1    |  sitting
|  3    |  sitting
|  5    |  sitting
|  9    |  running
|  10   |  running
|  11   |  sitting
|  13   |  sitting
|  15   |  walking
|  18   |  walking
|  20   |  running
|  31   |  sitting
|  32   |  sitting
```

Is there an easy way to get a list of the start/stop times for each activity?  Thus my result would be:

```
sitting (1, 5)
sitting (9, 10)
sitting (11, 13)
running (9, 10)
running (20, 20)
walking (15, 18)
```

I know I could do a greedy search and, for each activity, gather the start/stop times each unique cluster and store them that way.  But as this data is stored in an sqlite file I'd like to think there would be a query I could write to quickly give me the same data I am looking for.  The data does not have to be in the exact format as I listed it below but rather give me all start/stop times for all occurrences of like activities...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL is a set-oriented language, so the query, while working, is not pretty:

```sql
SELECT activity,
       time AS start_time,
       (SELECT MAX(a3.time)
        FROM activity AS a3
        WHERE a3.time < ifnull((SELECT MIN(time)
                                FROM activity AS a4
                                WHERE a4.time > a1.time
                                  AND a4.activity != a1.activity),
                               'inf')
       ) AS end_time
FROM activity AS a1
WHERE (SELECT a2.activity
       FROM activity AS a2
       WHERE a2.time < a1.time
       ORDER BY a2.time DESC
       LIMIT 1
      ) IS NOT a1.activity
```

How it works:

The outer query (`a1`) returns a record for every start of a group.
A record is the start of a group if it is the *first* record with an activity, i.e., if the previous record has a different activity.
The previous record is the record with the largest time that is still smaller, and is computed by the `a2` subquery.
The comparison uses `IS NOT` instead of `!=` because the subquery returns `NULL` if there is no previous record.

The third column, computed by the `a3` subquery, gives the end time of the group.
The last record of the group is the last record before the first record of the next group.
The first record of the next group (computed by the `a4` subquery) is the record with the smallest timestamp that is still larger but has a different activity.
At the end of the table, there is no next group; the `ifnull` converts that `NULL` into the string `'inf'` which compares larger than any number.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks!  One last question, can this be modified to only show items in a range?  For example if time is greater than 3?  I tried making all of the a#.time's greater than my range but that didn't work....

Comment: What time? Start? End? Length?

Comment: I guess I meant is it possible to perform the same query as above but limit the query to a certain range over the ENTIRE table.  For example, I am only interested in finding the ranges for the subset of all data tuples where the time is greater than 9.  So essentially get the same results as I would with your original query but omit any data whose timestamps are 9 or earlier.  If i need to write a new question I will :)

Comment: Add `AND WHERE start_time > 9` at the end.

Comment: I tried that but got an error saying I cannot do that 'Error: near "WHERE": syntax error'

Comment: Sorry, I meant `AND start_time > 9`.

Comment: That ALMOST works.  That code will remove the entire cluster of consecutive values, not just the ones in question.  Continuing with my example if I chose `AND start_time > 9` I would expect the first entry in my results to be a single instance of `running` with time stamp 10.  This query as written will remove the entire tuple.

Comment: Then add the same condition to the `a2` subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a1.activity, min(a1.time), max(a2.time)
from activity as a1 
   inner join activity as a2 on a1.activity = a2.activity
group by a1.activity
```

performance hint: make sure of you have activity index

Comment: This merges the start/stop times of activities that are interrupted by *other* activities.